# While create unique index with condition getting syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

While creating unique index with condition getting syntax error. Below is table structure and index

```
CREATE TABLE Location(
    GId bigint NOT NULL,
    MTypeId smallint NOT NULL,
    RemovedIndex int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_Location ON Location 
(
    GId, 
    MTypeId,
    RemovedIndex
) 
WHERE 
    (MTypeId NOT IN (6, 14) );
```

Why I am getting error, Instead of NOT IN, if change to IN it is working but that's not requirement

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: `WHERE 
    (MTypeId <> 6 and  MTypeId <> 14 )`

Comment: working fine for me. What sql server you have?

Comment: See the section “What You Can’t do …” https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-filtered-indexes/

Comment: The OP has tagged [[tag:sql-server-2017]], @MuhammadSaqlain , so presumably SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Yes, @astentx this link works for me, What You Can’t do in a Filtered Index…
Use certain expressions, such as BETWEEN, NOT IN, or a CASE statement.